# Custom Gridview in ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I have problem with my Custom Gridview. I have done it according to this solution [Custom GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut) I have image bellow gridview,on all device it work correctly except devices with layout-sw360 (Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy S3). Text below last two element of grid not displayed fully. Thanks for help and sorry for bad english

[image: problem]

My Layout

```
<ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <cz.xx.xxx.utils.CustomGridView
                    android:id="@+id/productGridview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:listSelector="#00000000"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            </cz.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomGridView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_dobre_jistoty"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="obr"
                android:src="@drawable/img_cdjabout" 
                android:onClick="cdjClick"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use   **android:fillViewport="true"** in the scrollview and set the layout height to match your content.

Like this:

```
<ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="500dp"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:fillViewport="true">
```