# insert more than 2 gridview in a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gridview

im trying to insert 6 gridviews with 6 imageview above each of them ! the problem im facing is that i cant scroll my page to see all my girdviews the first gridview seems fine as it wraps all its contents and set the height to it the second gridview shows only first row and make it scrollable but i can't see my other gridviews i want a layout like
--ImageView--
--GridView1--
--ImageView--
--GridView2--
--ImageView--
--GridView3--
and so on

```
<LinearLayout>
<ImageView />
<GridView />
--
--
<GridView6 />
</LinearLayout>
```

i have tried using scrollview and all but couldn't get the results !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hee is how you can do this. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut). It is an expandable height GridView, which you will want to import / create in your project. What that basically means is that as more items are added to the GridView, it will just expand its height, as opposed to keeping its height set and using scrolling. This is exactly what you want.

Once you have the ExpandableHeightGridView in your project, go to your XML layout where you want the GridView to be. You can then do something like this (paraphrasing):

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <RelativeLayout ...>
        <com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView ... />
        <other view items />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, in your activity where you set the GridView's adapter, you want to make sure you set it to expand. So:

```
ExpandableHeightGridView gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
gridView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
gridView.setExpanded(true);
```

The reason you want this expandable GridView is because, the fact that a standard GridView doesn't expand is what causes it to scroll. It sticks to a certain height, and then as more items fill it past its view bounds, it becomes scrollable. Now, with this, your GridView will always expand its height to fit the content within it, thus never allowing it to enter its scrolling mode. This enables you to use it inside of the ScrollView and use other view elements above or below it within the ScrollView, and have them all scroll.

This should give you the result you're looking for. Let me know if you have any questions.