# Scroll only GridView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a custom GridView inside a ScrollView. I used this example :

[Gridview height gets cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut/8483078#8483078)

It works fine now !

But what I want, is to make ONLY the GridView scrolling and disable the scroll of the parent ScrollView.
I tried with this example :

[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

But it's not working at all.

How can I do that please ?

Comment: its not a good way to put gridView inside a scrollView.

Comment: Yes but I really need it.

Comment: GridView is basically a ListView with columns. All of the same concepts apply. Putting a ListView or GridView into a ScrollView is like trying to parse HTML with regex. Your only reward for the attempt will be pain and misery.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a RelativeLayout called griditem

2) Develop a your self ListAdapter

3) Grid layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

4) Fill the adapter with a GridView

```
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.griditem, R.id.title,
                contentList);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how to put a listview inside a scroll view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view). It shows how to do it using a listview, worth a look.. :)