# GridView specific items number height

Tags: android

I have GridView in LinearLayout in Fragment. I'm using ViewPager with few fragments, one in each page. Under ViewPager i have indicator. I'm using RelativeLayout as a root of layout and ViewPager is above indicator. Every of fragments in pager have GridView with 4 cells (2 columns x 2 rows).

In phone everything looks alright, but when i run my app on tablet i have a lot of empty space under GridView. One row of GridView have height in about 1/4 of available space, so GridView using only 1/2 empty space. In every cell i have only ImageView, and for some reason it looks like there have margins in sides.

How can measure and set height for row or cell or gridview? I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut/8483078#8483078) but its not work for me.

Comment: give different diemnsions to imageview for tablet

Comment: how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file dimens.xml in values directory.
Put there

```
     <dimen name="row_height">300dp</dimen>.
```

This is default size.

Create directory values-large inside res folder.

Create file dimens.xml in values-large directory.
Put there

```
  <dimen name="row_height">600dp</dimen>
```

This is size for tab

and inside layout file add

```
  android:layout_width="@dimen/row_height"
```