# GridView item is not scrolling inside Expandable list

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I have a expandable list,inside that first child is Gridview.  here i had issue of gridview height cut. that i solved by using this solution: [Gridview height gets cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut).

Now i'm getting new issue is, not able to scroll the gridview item under some fixed height. I need to add scroller here because there is a possibility that gridview item can grow dynamically.

i'm able to do this with normal gridview, but showing this annoying issue under expandable listview.

code:

```
 <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/Explst"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:transcriptMode="disabled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp" />
```

Gridview in expandable list custom layout:

```
  <mynamespace.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

custom expandableheightgridview.cs

```
mynamespace 
{
      public class ExpandableHeightGridView :GridView
    {
        bool _isExpanded = false;

        public ExpandableHeightGridView (Context context) : base (context)
        {            
        }

        public ExpandableHeightGridView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
        {            
        }

        public ExpandableHeightGridView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
        {            
        }

        public bool IsExpanded {
            get { return _isExpanded; }

            set { _isExpanded = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        { 
            if (IsExpanded) { 
                int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (View.MeasuredSizeMask, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
                base.OnMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);                

                var layoutParameters = this.LayoutParameters;
                layoutParameters.Height = this.MeasuredHeight;
            } else {
                base.OnMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);    
            } 
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        } 
    }

}
```

Any suggestion/hints/links are appreciable.
I'm trying this in xamarin.android c#, but even any java android solutions are also helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must set expand=true;

```
mExpandGrid= (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.mExpandGrid);
mExpandGrid.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: Yes I did that already. Expand is working without any issue. But not able to set  scroller  for  that grid items, which is expandable list child.